# Select PHP Switch case values from mysql

Tags: php, mysql, switch-statement, case

I have a db table

Table: example_tbl

```
| amount   | recurring | frequency    |
| 100      | 150       |  8,monthly   |
| 200      | 250       |  1,annually  |
```

I am trying to select the frequency values in a switch, it just does not want to work, I assume this is due to the comma values in the frequency column. Any help appreciated:

```
    switch($item['frequency'])
    {
        case 'monthly':
            code here....
            break;
        case 'annually':                                
            code here... 
            break;                
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: you shouldn't be storing such 'dual-value' values in your table. if 8 means monthly, and 1 means annually, you're just wasting space by duplicating the data, and could end up with a degenerate sitaution where you've got `1,monthly` and `8,annually` because of a logic error something.

Answer (score 4):

You are right. Use explode:

```
$parts = explode(",", $item["frequency"]);
$frequency = $parts[1];
```

Now use $frequency in your switch case:

```
switch($frequency)
{
    case 'monthly':
        code here....
        break;
    case 'annually':                                
        code here... 
        break;                
}
```

Read more about explode here http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php. Explode tokenizes your string using the given delimiter.